# Calculating properties from S-S curve

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Alright, for this data is it correct to get young modulus as 16GPa please and resilience as 14j/mm^3??

For resilience is it just 1/2(stress)(strain at yield)?

Stress is first column in MPa

Cheers lads

[![stress is first column in MPa  ][1]][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy26y.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy26y.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdUou.jpg)

Comment: Can you plot the S-S diagram and show how you get E = 17 GPa, please.

Comment: Hi so I tried to upload it but it says it too big?

Comment: I don't know the size limit here. But if you couldn't downsize the file, maybe you can leave it in a dropbox and provide the link.

Comment: There that should be it